# Unable to delete a file with services

Tags: 7, ajax, services

I am making an AJAX call to /file/.json. Webserver log says `DELETE /services/file/5710.json HTTP/1.1 200`, console log says the file has been deleted; yet the file is still there when you go [here](http://www.rejicast.com/services/file/5710.json). What am I missing? My code is as follows:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.rejicast.com/services/file/' + oldFID + '.json',
  type: "delete",
  dataType: "json",
  beforeSend: function(r) {
    r.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token.token)
  },
  success: function() {
    console.log('Deleted the file');
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    console.error(xhr);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(err);
  }
})
```

(Note: oldFID is something I set at the beginning)

UPDATE: As per @Clive's answer, there is still a reference to the file in the database as seen below [image: here].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file *reference* has been deleted, i.e. the record in the `file_managed` table; the file itself will be deleted later during the [`system_cron`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_cron/7.x) run.

See the 10 or so lines under this comment in that function:

```
// Remove temporary files that are older than DRUPAL_MAXIMUM_TEMP_FILE_AGE.
```

Comment: Reference to the file is still there is the database - please see https://www.dropbox.com/s/7kbwvvjg5sp95s1/Screenshot%202016-06-08%2013.44.39.png

Comment: If you have additional info please make sure it's added to the question, not linked from elsewhere. Without having access to your site (or getting more information) I can only guess that there's a bug in the Services module in that case. If it says it's deleted, but it's not deleted, I'd open a bug report up immediately

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug - [`_file_resource_delete`](http://www.rit.edu/drupal/api/drupal/sites!all!modules!services!resources!file_resource.inc/function/_file_resource_delete/7.41) does very little, just calls core `file_delete` really and returns the result. If you're getting a positive response, but the file isn't deleted, Services or `file_delete` are lying to you